# Pandas: creating dataframe from numpy preserving the original format

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe, precision

Say you have this numpy array:

```
a=array([[  9.81650352,  10.03896523,  10.26972675],...])
```

how can you preserve the 8 (or n) decimal digits it has when you create the following dataframe?

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'column':a})
```

Comment: I think it is only display problem. You can change parameter `precision`, check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options) - `In [63]: pd.set_option('precision',n)`

Comment: Isn't this just a display issue? the actual values are preserved as pandas will take a view on the underlying numpy buffer, you should be able to confirm this by doing `df.values`

Comment: I was just wondering. If you apply some sort of *vertical look up* function, wouldn't this cause problems because it cannot find the exact values in the dataframe?

Comment: @CF84 That's a floating pt issue, different issue altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above, and for future reference, [this is the way to go](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options) if there are `8` decimals:

```
import numpy
import pandas

a=array([[  9.81650352,  10.03896523,  10.26972675]])
pandas.set_option('precision',8)
df = pandas.DataFrame({'column':a})
```